How do I stop ASP.NET Core from initializing DataProtection? I am absolutely confident this application cannot and does not use it
How do I stop ASP.NET Core from initializing DataProtection? I am absolutely confident this application cannot and does not use it.
The ASP.NET Core startup code:
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("devsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var config = builder.Build();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            // Snip kestrel initialization noise
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((logging) =>
        {
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Enum.Parse<LogLevel>(config.GetValue("LogLevel", "Warning")));
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseIIS()
        .ConfigureServices((services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IStartup>((sp) => new Startup(config));
        })
        .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, "Cedaron.FormBuilder.WebAPI")
        //.UseApplicationInsights()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .Build();

host.Run();

Startup is completely bland:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>((options) => options.AllowSynchronousIO = true);
    services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints((endpoints) => endpoints.MapControllers());
}

IServiceProvider IStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    ConfigureServices(services);
    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}

void IStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    Configure(app);
}

I am the author of the sole controller in this application. It doesn't use so much as sessions in any normal sense. Each request is complete and independent of itself, and is authenticated by a completely outside mechanism.
This application is not called from a browser but rather from the web server. It has no want nor need of any on-disk data protection store.
How do I get rid of it? I don't want it on the disk at all.
Whenever the application starts it creates an .aspnet/DataProtection-Keys. I want it gone.

Hi @Joshua, have you tried services.AddDataProtection().UseEphemeralDataProtectionProvider();   to use an in-memory store for keys?

@marc_s Not sure why you deleted the begin/end code block markers.

Because they're not needed (to get proper syntax highlighting) and they just indent the code too far to the right, for no reason

I think you want PersistKeysToFileSystem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0#persistkeystofilesystem  (but probably not the most secure thing to do... if your app ever uses keys for things like anti-forgery, you would want to protect those keys and DPAPI is really good at protecting them)

@browsermator: More like, I want persist keys to bitbucket. anti-forgerery can't be used because again this is not called by a browser and trying to call this with a JS fetch completely bypassing cors wouldn't even work.
